# VScode C# intellisence scanning wrong files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I have a problem. When I'm programming, the local history extension does backups of files, but c# intelligence scanning these files. The problem is when local history will do backup with an error in code. After this, in my VScode I see a lot of errors from backup files. I tried to exclude .history folder in the VScode, but it didn't help. What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: have you try delete the obj and bin folder?

Comment: No, but why should I do this? I don't understand.

Comment: When you run your program, the obj and bin folders are created automatically. If the history file still has binaries in that folder, try to delete it first. and see what happens

Comment: local history extension creates backup of .cs files.